# Are the following systems of inequalities the same?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$,  and $\mathcal{S_1}$ is a system of inequalities:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{S_1} &= \begin{Bmatrix}
x  -  y  \geq 1\\
-x + 2y \geq 1\\
3x - 5y  \geq 2
\end{Bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{Bmatrix}
x  \geq 1 + y\\
x  \leq 2y-1\\
x  \geq \frac{2+5y}{3}
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align*}

I eliminate $x$ from $S_1$ to obtain $S_2$:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{S_2} &= \begin{Bmatrix}
1+y \leq 2y -1 \\
\frac{2+5y}{3} \leq 2y-1
\end{Bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{Bmatrix}
2 \leq y \\
2+5y \leq 6y-3
\end{Bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{Bmatrix}
2 \leq y \\
5 \leq y
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Therefore, I know that $5 \leq y < \infty$. Let $S_3$ denote the following system of inequalities

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{S_3} &= \begin{Bmatrix}
x  -  y  \geq 1\\
-x + 2y \geq 1\\
3x - 5y  \geq 2\\
5 \leq y < \infty
\end{Bmatrix}
\end{align*}

My question is, is $S_3 = S_1$?

Comment: Look at the $x-y \geq 1$ inequality. It should become $x\geq 1+y$. This changes to give $y\geq 2$ instead. Yes, the sets are the same as all operations don't change the amount of info.

Comment: This is the question you asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123828/does-fourier-motzkin-elimination-change-the-solution-set).

Comment: @MSE, you're right, the two questions are similar,  but technically, $S_3$ is not the end result of what one would get from doing FME. I wanted to double-check that $S_1 = S_3$ holds.

Comment: @AdamKarlson Sorry I'm not following.  What do you mean by this changes to give $y \geq 2$ instead?

Comment: @Adrian Oh, I am saying that the there is a mistake in the line I pointed out. Try doing it again

Comment: @AdamKarlson, Oh I see. Thanks. I've updated my post. Would you like to post your  comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $S_3=S_1$. We need only to show that

$$5≤y<\infty$$

Therefore, we have,

$$3(-x+2y)+3x-5y≥3\times 1+2 $$

$$\iff y≥5.$$

---

But, this notation is problematic.

$$5≤y≤\infty$$

The correct one can be written as follows:

$$5≤y<\infty$$

Or,

$$y\in[5,+\infty)$$